# how to start Crontab in Django Project locally?

Tags: python, django, cron, cron-task, django-cron

I still pretty new to the use of crontab in Django. I have followed the instruction in this link https://hprog99.wordpress.com/2014/08/14/how-to-setup-django-cron-jobs/ to help me set up my method, my_scheduled_job() in cron.py file, which I want to call every five minutes.

Here is my updated setting.py

`INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django_crontab',
    ...)
CRONJOBS = [
    ('*/5 * * * *', 'myproject.cron.my_scheduled_job')
]`

After which I ran this: `python manage.py crontab add`

Output: `adding cronjob: (d0428c9ae8227ed78b17bf32aca4bc67) -> ('*/5 * * * *', 'cinemas.cron.my_scheduled_job')`

Next: Nothing happens.

How do I start this cron job locally? Is there a way to test if my job ran normally?

Comment: I resolved this by running python manage.py runserver.  Function started running at every 5th minute interval yay!

Answer (score 2):

In django you can setup cron using [django-chronograph](https://github.com/t11e/django-chronograph) or [chronograph](http://django-chronograph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html).

Django-chronograph is a simple application that allows you to control the frequency at which a Django management command gets run.

**Step 1**:
Create management command of your task in django. For creating django management command refer [Writing custom django-admin commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/).

**Step 2**:
After creating django management command configure command in cronograph.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: django-chronograph is unmaintained. Its fork is doing much better and has support for Django 2.0 and Django 2.1: https://github.com/chrisspen/django-chroniker

Answer (score 1):

first, you must Specify your project profile, then add the cron job, if your project name is foo, then it is like:

```
export FOO_PROFILE = 'local'
python manage.py crontab add
```

and , before run above command, in your settings.local you should config cron environment first, something like:

```
# django-crontab config
CRONTAB_DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = 'gold.settings.local'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a test tab in Python?  Probably a simulation somewhere to get tutorial.  Try key word search in agent answer or similar help and command program.

Answer (score 0):

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Once you start the server, crontab will automatically execute based on the time specified in settings.py.

Answer (score 0):

Realistically what you want is to create a Django command and make a job entry in crontab -e to call that command.